# How can I retrive facebook comments commented on my website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook comments on my website but is there any way to get the comments of my website post.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve facebook comments for your URL trough the Graph API. Simply make an HTTP GET request to:

In the following example replace `<Your token>` with your access token

```js
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=https://stackoverflow.com/&access_token=<Your token>", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
```